# Grid or flexbox to achieve this design

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I would like to have the following structure :

- First row : 3 columns
- Second rows : 2 columns

Here is the images describing the need for desktop :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/L0kHU.png

How can I achieve this, with Css grid, Flexbox or other solution ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flexbox is more appropriate to have such a layout

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.child {
  background-color: teal;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Doesn't exactly give the desired result, since they are asking for specific number of columns

Comment: If you want to vary the number of column you can either reduce the parent width or increase the child width

Comment: Thank you I will try and keep you updated

Comment: It works with added with. Thank you !

Comment: Cool ! 
You can chose the answer if it helps you :)

Answer (score 0):

`grid-template` can get this done. Usage:

```css
grid-template: 150px / auto auto auto;
```

Creates 3 columns, then for mobile, just do

```css
grid-template: 150px / auto auto;
```

Creates 2 columns

Comment: Thank you I will try tomorrow and keep you updated

Comment: It works. Both answers are good.